# AppEngine serves blank page on the first request - what is the difference between first and subsequent instance loads?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am having a problem with the AppEngine serving me a blank page every time the instance is loaded. 
It is similar problem already covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578453/blank-page-but-no-error-python-appengine), however, there was no constructive solution mentioned that would help my case.

As there are no errors in the console, this one seems to be extremely hard to debug and I frankly do not know how to start. I have not solution mentioned in the previous post as I do not want to rename any of my files and I want to keep my code organised as it is now.

Lastly, to ask a broader question - **what is the difference the first and subsequent requests are handled for each of the instances?** Is there anything a developer should be aware of?

So what exactly happens - if the appengine's code is loaded for the first time, I get a blank page. Every subsequent request is fine. I think I have all the required parts of the code there, just in case here are the handlers from app.yaml (also, the app is using python27 as a platform):

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /fb/.*
  script: fbhandler.py

- url: /xarpc/.*
  script: xmlrpchandler.py

- url: /
  script: main.py

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

The handler in question is the fbhandler.py.

```
def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([("/fb/", FBHandler)], debug=True)

    util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I examine the appengine logs, I see this for the "blank" request:

```
2012-05-07 10:43:14.822 /fb/?id=341108955956205 200 2998ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19
95.23.245.xx - - [07/May/2012:03:43:14 -0700] "POST /fb/?id=xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=2999 cpu_ms=563 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.015744 loading_request=1 instance=00c61b117cb0ca2fc61adc3939c4bd034dfa416f
I 2012-05-07 10:43:14.822
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

Compared to this for any good subsequent request:

```
2012-05-07 10:44:05.479 /fb/?id=341108955956205 200 832ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19
95.23.245.xx - - [07/May/2012:03:44:05 -0700] "POST /fb/?id=xxx HTTP/1.1" 200 483 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.168 Safari/535.19" "xxx.appspot.com" ms=832 cpu_ms=1272 api_cpu_ms=1078 cpm_usd=0.035497 instance=00c61b117cb0ca2fc61adc3939c4bd034dfa416f
```

As you can see, no obvious error messages anywhere.

**Update**:
Upon advice, I have removed the main() to try to rule out caching, now the handler looks like:

```
application = webapp.WSGIApplication([("/fb/", FBHandler)], debug=True)
util.run_wsgi_app(application)
```

Same effect, first load gets blank page and subsequent loads get proper data. What I have noticed that it does not matter if a new code is uploaded or not, if an instance is running and I update the code, it shows properly on the first load. I need to go into instances admin and shut one down to reproduce the error.

**Update 2**:
I have now tried changing the handlers to the new python27 way:

```
- url: /fb/.*
  script: fbhandler.app
```

And also corresponding change to the fbhandler

```
import webapp2
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([("/fb/", FBHandler)])
```

Again, same issue. I have also tried removing the debug parameter with no effect.

Comment: Is there any chance that you have changed your app.yaml to the py27-supported way of specifying the app directly rather than the script file, e.g.
  script: myapp.app ?  
If so, and you are also loading main() (which you would not then need), I believe you can see this behaviour.

Comment: hi - I now have changed it to the python27-way, still the same behaviour. One more thing - I am using `threadsafe: false`, could that be a factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I now seem to have found a solution. When I upgraded all of the application handlers to the webapp2 and used the new way of referencing them, it now seems to work without the first load error.

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing this behavior due to the way App Engine caches your CGI handler.
If you look in the [runtime documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime) (CGI Handler Scripts Can Also Be Cached
section) you can see that:

> You can tell App Engine to cache the CGI handler script itself, in addition to imported modules. If the handler script defines a function named main(), then the script and its global environment will be cached like an imported module. The first request for the script on a given web server evaluates the script normally. For subsequent requests, App Engine calls the main() function in the cached environment.

To be sure that your handler works properly even during a instance startup be sure to define your WSGI application as a global variable (outside of main).

Comment: Ok, I get the difference now - but still, why would it behave differently? All the required parts of the code are there. Will try to define the application globally, leaving the util run the only contents of the main method

Comment: Not really helping - I have now tried removing the "main" - adding a blank parameter to it should stop it from being cached. Same behaviour.